# Bootstrap page organization bug

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

a huge pleasure to be part of this community. I'm new to web programming, so I apologize if you're asking any stupid questions. My question is this, I decided to create a page using items I already had on another page on my site. On the original page, there are several line graphics and pie charts organized, on this new page I would like to organize with four pie charts and two graphs online underneath. However, every time I rearrange the graphics, the graphics js plugin is nullified somehow, causing the graphics to disappear. What am I doing wrong?

Original page:http://tratspay.com/app/index.html
New page: http://tratspay.com/app/detalhamentoteste.html

```
<!-- /.row --> 
  <!-- Main row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-xlg-3">
      <div class="info-box">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
          <div>
            <h4 class="text-black">SRC que mais rentável</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m-t-2">
            <canvas id="pie-chart" height="210"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-xlg-3">
      <div class="info-box">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
          <div>
            <h4 class="text-black">Estado mais rentáveis</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m-t-2">
            <canvas id="pie-chart" height="210"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-xlg-3">
      <div class="info-box">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
          <div>
            <h4 class="text-black">Estados com maior conversão de boletos</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m-t-2">
            <canvas id="pie-chart" height="210"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-xlg-3">
      <div class="info-box">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
          <div>
            <h4 class="text-black">Maiores motivos de reembolso</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m-t-2">
            <canvas id="pie-chart" height="210"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-xlg-9">
      <div class="info-box">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
          <div>
            <h4 class="text-black">Relatório de Vendas</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="ml-auto">
            <ul class="list-inline">
              <li class="text-info"> <i class="fa fa-circle"></i> Este mês</li> <li class="text-blue"> <i class="fa fa-circle"></i> Mês Anterior</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div>
```

Comment: give different id's for pie charts

Comment: @Igor Rosa, I would appreciate you reviewing my answer to your question and if I was able to help you, marking answer as accepted by clicking on `v` under the answer's score. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp)

You cannot have multiple `<canvas id="pie-chart">` elements